# Copying of List in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As we know to copy list we have to copy() method, otherwise changes of values could happen. Just like this one:

**1st CODE:**

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 12]
list2 = list1
print('List1: ',list1)
print('List2: ',list2)
list2.append('new_val')
print('Updated_List1: ',list1)
print('Updated_List2: ',list2)
```

**It's O/P:**

```
List1:  ['a', 'b', 12]
List2:  ['a', 'b', 12]
Updated_List1:  ['a', 'b', 12, 'new_val']
Updated_List2:  ['a', 'b', 12, 'new_val']
```

***Above code i got it. BUT IF WE DO LIKE THIS(below code):***

**2nd CODE:**

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 12]
list2 = list1
list3 = ['x','y','z']
list2 = list2 + list3
print('List1: ',list1)
print('List2: ',list2)
print('List3: ',list3)
```

***IT's O/P:***

```
List1:  ['a', 'b', 12]
List2:  ['a', 'b', 12, 'x', 'y', 'z']
List3:  ['x', 'y', 'z']
```

**Here you can see, 1st code: changes in list2 affects list1 too. But in 2nd code: it's not happening. Can anyone explain why is this happening or i'm missing something?**

Comment: I guess checking the link will give you the solution https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: In your second code: list1, list2 and list3 are three different lists. They're not different references to the same list.

Comment: On the contrary, `list1` and `list2` are references to the same mutable list in first example

Answer (score 3):

In first code, list2 is just a reference of list1, hence change in list2 affects list1.

Type `id(list1)` and `id(list2)`, they should be the same in case of first code implying that `list1` and `list2` have the same address in the memory and they are the same (The `id(object)` prints the memory location of the object in python).

In the second code, that's not the case. The statment `list2 = list2 + list3` creates a new copy of list2 in memory. Checking for `id(list1)` and `id(list2)` will be different now.

Maybe checking the docs for [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) will be helpful.

Comment: You are absolutely right! 1st code: ids are same for list1&list2. But for 2nd Code: all ids are different. That means if we do list2=list1, it will create reference but we add anything to it afterwards like, list2 = list2+list3, reference part will get over and will create a new variable in memory? Am i right? and why exactly is it happening?

Comment: From my understanding of copy, you are right! In `list2 = list2 + list3`, a new compound object (`list2`) will be created which does not happen in `list2 = list1`.

Comment: Clearly `list2 + list3` creates a new list. How could the resulting list have the appropriate contents if it was not a new list?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```py
list1 = [ *list2 ]
```

to copy items of `list2` to `list1`. It creates a new list object having the items of `list2` then assigns to `list1`

N.B: Don't use it for nested lists

Comment: It makes a copy, but not a deep-copy. If an element of `list2` is a list and the content of that is modified, then it will also be modified in `list1`.

Comment: Thanks, @md2perpe for the clarification